# How to define a "Stroke style" parameter on the .inx file of an Inkscape extension?

Tags: inkscape

I'm trying to create a new Inkscape extension for a project, and I would be great to be able to control the Stroke style and the colour in the extension tab, like this:

[image]

I have tried looking it up in the [documentation](http://wiki.inkscape.org/wiki/index.php/INX_Parameters) but there's no description of how to set the stroke style.

I have been able to create a colour selection parameter like this:
`<param name="colour" type="color" gui-text="Colour: ">0</param>`

Is there any way to define a style selection in the same way?

Answer (score 1):

You can use an extension to modify the SVG contents programmatically (i.e. add a stroke to an object by modifying its representation in the Object tree).

Edit: Sorry, I misunderstood previously.

You can only use the available input types, which are listed here:
http://wiki.inkscape.org/wiki/index.php/INX_Parameters

So, use number input fields or multiselection to get what you still need beyond color.

Comment: I see, thanks for that! Do you know where I can find how to change these things on the script side? (I'm using Python)

Comment: @ebernardes Can you be more specific about what info you're looking for? I don't want to add a wrong reply a second time :)

Comment: I'm mostly interested in setting the dashed style of the lines, the width and the units (mm, px, in, etc).

Comment: Take a look into other extensions, how they set the style of an object. I think a good example for this would be the calendar extension - that sets fill color and font face according to user entries in the extension's gui. For the dashes, you'd probably have to present a custom selection of dashes, or to let the user set the pattern themselves, using numbers for dash and gap.

I think a unit selector is already available, and contains the units Inkscape knows about.